# android convert hour to minute

Tags: android, hour

```
    et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);
    et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et2);

    floatET1 = Float.parseFloat(et1.getText().toString());
    floatET2 = Float.parseFloat(et2.getText().toString());

    et1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                float sonuc1 = floatET2 * 60;
                et2.setText(sonuc1);
            }
        }
    });

    et2.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                float sonuc2 = floatET1  / 60;
                et1.setText(sonuc2);
```

when i click EditText (et2) then i want to calculating to minute and when i click to     EditText (et1) then convert to hour... but i doesn't work :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do what you want, although you probably want to inform the user with a toast message or something rather than quietly doing nothing when the input values aren't valid strings.

```
et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);
et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et2);

et1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            try {
                floatET2 = Float.parseFloat(et2.getText().toString());
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            }
            float sonuc1 = floatET2 * 60;
            et1.setText(String.valueOf(sonuc1));
        }
    }
});

et2.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            try {
                floatET1 = Float.parseFloat(et1.getText().toString());
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            }
            float sonuc2 = floatET1 / 60;
            et2.setText(String.valueOf(sonuc2));
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting your edittext content too early. Move the part involving `getText()` to the focus change listener.

Comment: also `et2.setText(String.valueOf(sonuc1));`

Answer (score 0):

You need to check input type of edittext.
If user enters value like 1.6, then your code is not working.
So make sure to provide input type then you can right your logic to calculate minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You need move:

```
 floatET1 = Float.parseFloat(et1.getText().toString());
 floatET2 = Float.parseFloat(et2.getText().toString());
```

into every

```
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

}
```

Because you need get the text in every focus change.

Then you should convert the result of operation into String (you are trying set a float value in setTex() method):

```
et1.setText(""+sonuc2);
et2.setText(""+sonuc1);
```

or

```
et1.setText(sonuc2.toString());
et2.setText(sonuc1.toString());
```